# Как записать информацию в файл Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть папка с папками, в каждой из них лежит несколько markdown файлов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно  пройтись по этим файлам и на выходе получить документ в котором будут записаны все заголовки #Title из этих маркдаунов.
В файле должна быть такая структура :

```
   folderName1
      fileName
        Title1
        Title2
    folderName2
      fileName
        Title3
        Title5
    ...
```

Я написал скрипт :

```
var {
  lstatSync,
  readdirSync,
  readFileSync,
  statSync,
  createWriteStream
} = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

const isDirectory = source => lstatSync(source).isDirectory();

function writeDoc(dir, fileTypes) {
  function walkDir(currentPath) {
    let files = readdirSync(currentPath);

    const CreateFiles = createWriteStream("./file.txt", {
      flags: "a" //flags: 'a' preserved old data
    });

    const headingsRegex = /^#(?!#)(.*)/gm;

    for (let i in files) {
      var curFile = path.join(currentPath, files[i]);
      if (isDirectory(curFile)) {
        CreateFiles.write("FOLDER_NAME-->" + curFile.split("/").pop() + "\r\n");
        walkDir(curFile);
      } else if (
        statSync(curFile).isFile() &&
        fileTypes.indexOf(path.extname(curFile)) != -1
      ) {
        CreateFiles.write("FILE_NAME--->" + curFile.split("/").pop() + "\r\n");

        const fileData = readFileSync(curFile, "utf8");

        let match = headingsRegex.exec(fileData);

        while (match != null) {
          CreateFiles.write("HEADER--->" + match[1] + "\r\n");
          match = headingsRegex.exec(fileData);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  walkDir(dir);
}

writeDoc("./templates", [".md"]);
```

Который рекурсивно проходить по папкам и вытягивает заголовки но на выходе у меня в файл записываеться не то что я ожидаю :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем моя ошибка ?

Comment: Хорошо бы еще в вопрос добавить пример содержимого хотя бы двух файлов. Полагаю, что ошибка у вас регулярном выражении, в части `(.*)`.

Comment: У меня изначально не правильно цыкл работает

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я регулярку проверил в онлайн редакторе,  с ней все норм. Возможно в самом коде что то не так с цыклами ?

Comment: Какой цикл вы имеете в виду? У вас регулярка не правильно работает, поэтому цикл while и не работает. Например, проверьте на данных `↵#1 ggg↵↵2↵#3↵↵4`

Comment: Вы правы на этом примере не работает, но скрипт сначала выводит все файлы а в конце файлы с содержимым, тогда это проблема не только в регулярке?

Comment: Я не понял, что это значит * но скрипт сначала выводит все файлы а в конце файлы с содержимым*. У вас есть файлы без содержимого? Или что вы этим хотели сказать?